# Can I create a new parameter for video_mode of camera1394

Tags: ros, calibration, camera1394, camera, camera-calibration

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Currently, I have my firefly mv usb camera working with camera1394 package. The problem is that the maximum resolution of my camera is 1328x1048, but there is no parameter for 1328x1048 in video_mode. I am wondering can I create or modify a mode to enable 1328x1048 resolution works?
Thanks in advance.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49794/can-i-create-a-new-parameter-for-video_mode-of-camera1394/) by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on ROS Answers with karma: 441 on 2012-12-05

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The IIDC 1394 standard defines the available modes. Each camera provides some subset of those standard settings. So, no: you can't define your own video mode.

However, the standard also provides Format 7, which allows the camera to provide additional non-standard resolutions. Please consult your device-specific specifications to see if it provides a Format 7 option that supports the full resolution. Most do, often using Format 7 Mode 0.

**EDIT**:

Because Format 7 behavior is not specified by the standard, individual devices vary widely. Most cameras I have tested display full device resolution, generally when using Format 7 Mode 0.

The driver provides [special parameters only used in Format 7 modes](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394#Format7). You can experiment with them, but the default values normally provide the behavior you want. You can also try Format 7 Mode 1, Mode 2, etc.

To experiment with those parameters while the driver is running, use the [reconfigure GUI](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/Tutorials/SettingIEEE1394CameraParametersDynamically). Unfortunately, many cameras behave badly in Format 7 mode when given unexpected parameter values. If the device hangs while you are experimenting with those parameters, you may need to [perform various resets](http://www.ros.org/wiki/camera1394/Troubleshooting#Camera_Hung) to get it working again.

If that does not work, run coriander on the device. See what parameters it supports. Then set the equivalent values in camera1394.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2012-12-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-06**:
Hi joq, I remember Format 7 Mode 0 works for my camera in the morning. But the problem is that the resolution still keeps low. How can I define the resolution of Format 7 Mode 0 in camera1394 package?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-08**:
Thanks, I got it works.

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2012-12-08**:
Good. For the record: what modes and parameters did it take?

**Comment by [AdrianPeng](https://answers.ros.org/users/3585/adrianpeng/) on 2012-12-08**:
I just use format7_mode0 and change the encoding method to raw8.